# Posts not showing per category after WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query

I have a Query that goes in and should list all the categories for a post type and loop through and display all the posts within that category but I can't get it to work, it shows the posts in a seemingly random order?

It should, if there is no category set in the shortcode atts, just grab all the categories and list all the posts i.e.

KEBABS (category)
  Post 1
  Post 2
  Post 3

SIDES (category)
  Post 4
  Post 5
  Post 6

Any advice would be welcome. Thanks

```
//MENU SHORTCODE
add_shortcode('himenu', 'create_menu_shortcode');

function create_menu_shortcode ($atts){ 

    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'category' => '',
            'posts_per_page' => ''
        ), $atts, 'himenu' );

        $category = $atts["category"];


        ?> <div class=hi-menu-box><?php 
           // var_dump ($atts);
           // var_dump ($category);

            $args_cat = [
                'orderby' => 'name',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty' => 0,
                        ];

            $menu_categories = get_categories($args_cat);
            print_r($menu_categories);

            if (!empty($menu_categories) && !isset($category)){
                foreach ($menu_categories as $menu_category):

                        $args = [
                        'post_type' => 'menu_item',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'orderby' => 'title',
                        'category_name' => $category,
                        'cat' => $menu_category->term_id
                    ];      

                    $query = new WP_Query($args);
                    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>   

                        <div class="indi-menu-item"> 
                            <div class="menu-item-column">
                                <h5> <?php 
                                if($category === 'special-offers'){ echo "Special Offers";} else{the_category();} ?></h5>
                                <div class="menu-item-meta">
                                    <h4> <?php the_title(); ?></h4>                    
                                    <p><?php the_field('description')?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu-item-column">
                                <h2>£<?php the_field('price'); ?></h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>    


                   <?php endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                 endforeach;}

            else{

                    $args = [
                        'post_type' => 'menu_item',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'orderby' => 'title',
                        'category_name' => $category,
                        'cat' => $menu_category->term_id
                    ];      

                    $query = new WP_Query($args);
                    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>   

                        <div class="indi-menu-item"> 
                            <div class="menu-item-column">
                                <h5> <?php 
                                if($category === 'special-offers'){ echo "Special Offers";} else{the_category();} ?></h5>
                                <div class="menu-item-meta">
                                    <h4> <?php the_title(); ?></h4>                    
                                    <p><?php the_field('description')?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu-item-column">
                                <h2>£<?php the_field('price'); ?></h2>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    <?php endwhile;
                };?>
             </div>
    <?php wp_reset_query();
        };?>
```

Comment: can you please show me one shortcode you have use for this.